# Align divs in top and bottom of Bootstrap 5 col

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have a Bootstrap 5 row with multiple col's. Each col has an image and a paragraph.

The images have different height, so in order to align everything I want to:

1. give the child div a 100% height with `h-100`
2. align the image with the top with `align-top`
3. align the paragraph with the bottom with `align-bottom`

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="mt-5 col text-center">
    <div class="h-100 border">
      <div class="align-top">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="example1.png" width="180">
      </div>
      <div class="align-bottom">
        <p>Paragraph 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mt-5 col text-center">
    <div class="h-100 border">
      <div class="align-top">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="example2.png" width="180">
      </div>
      <div class="align-bottom">
        <p>Paragraph 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But `align-bottom` somehow have no effect. Most likely `align-top` don't either, but haven't checked since the default is to align in the top.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Use flexbox utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/vertical-align/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the following Bootstrap classes: `flex-grow-1 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-end`, where:

- `flex-grow-1` forces the text to always fill the remaining empty space below the image,
- `justify-content-center` centers the text horizontally and
- `align-items-end` pushes the text vertically to the bottom.

*Note: You can remove `id="img-1` and `id="img-2` (it's just for illustration purposes).*

See the snippet below.

```css
#img-1 {
  height: 200px !important;
}

#img-2 {
  height: 50px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="mt-5 col text-center">
    <div class="h-100 border">
      <div class="align-top">
        <img id="img-1" class="img-fluid" src="example1.png" width="180">
      </div>
      <div class="align-bottom d-flex justify-content-center">
        <p>Paragraph 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mt-5 col text-center">
    <div class="h-100 border d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="align-top">
        <img id="img-2" class="img-fluid" src="example2.png" width="180">
      </div>
      <div class="align-bottom flex-grow-1 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-end">
        <p>Paragraph 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Heh, align-items-end was the saver for my task :-). Knew it is there but was't able to find it in docs.